# PHP Extensions: Building Debug/Release & NTS/TS

Tags: php, build

I've been trying to streamline a build process for a PHP extension of mine. I ran into issues at first with debug/release inconsistencies, as well as NTS (Non Thread Safe) and TS inconsistencies.

I finally figured out how to deal with these problems (turn on/off various #defines in php_config.h).

EDIT: For googlers, the answer to turn off debug is to switch the ZEND_DEBUG #define to 0, and to turn thread safety off, remove entirely the #define for ZTS in php_config.h.

However, I have been editing the php_config.h found in the default location to do this (in /usr/local/php/whatever/whatever), and I would really like to be able to specify one at a custom, relative path. I've looked through (and tried) the options for ./configure and I'm either a fool and missed the one I need, or maybe it isn't there.

Can anyone confirm if such an option exists or does not exist, and how to use it?

Comment: Try the PECL guys on IRC - Efnet #php.pecl

Comment: Thanks, will do. This is a very specialized question :)

Comment: Also, I don't think you need to edit _php_config.h_ to disable thread safety; you should just be able to **--configure** w/o **--enable-maintainer-zts**, again the _pecl_dev_ list should be able to point you in the right direction (either on IRC or the mailing list).